# Ruby Hash deeply nested hash with arrays traversal

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash, nested

I have a deeply nested hash with arrays mixed in. the hash represent a graph like relationship. each node can have one or more connections to the next.

**Inputs/output:**
examples:

```
Given {'id' => biology}
results_should_be: {'biology' => {'id' => biology, 'paths' => [[{'id' => biology}]]}}

    Given {'id'=> biology, 'children' =>[{'id' => microbiology}, {'id' => physicalbio}]}
    results_should_be:
            {'biology' => {'id' => biology, 'paths' => [['id' => biology]]},
             "microbiology"=>{"id" => "microbiology", "paths" => [[{"id" => "biology"}, {"id" => "microbiology"}]]},
             "physicalbio"=>{"id" => "physicalbio", "paths" => [[{"id" => "biology"}, {"id" => "physicalbio"}]]}

    Given {'id'=> biology, 'children' =>[{'id' => microbiology, 'children' => [{'id' => physicalbio},{"id" => "physicalbio"}]}}
    results_should_be:
            {'biology' => {'id' => biology, 'paths' => [['id' => biology]]},
             "microbiology"=>{"id" => "microbiology", "paths" => [{"id" => "biology", "id" => "microbiology"}]},
             "physicalbio"=>{"id" => "physicalbio", "paths" => [[{"id" => "biology"}, {"id" => "physicalbio"}][{"id" => "biology"}, {"id" => "microbiology"},{"id" => "physicalbio"}]]}
```

My failing test result

```
 {"biology"=>{"id"=>"biology", "paths"=>[[{"id"=>"biology"}]]},
 "microbiology"=>
         {"id"=>"microbiology",
          "children"=>[{"id"=>"physicalbio", "paths"=>[[{"id"=>"microbiology"}, {"id"=>"physicalbio"}], [{"id"=>"biology"}, {"id"=>"microbiology"}, {"id"=>"physicalbio"}]]}],
          "paths"=>[[{"id"=>"biology"}, {"id"=>"microbiology"}]]},
 "physicalbio"=>{"id"=>"physicalbio", "paths"=>[[{"id"=>"biology"}, {"id"=>"physicalbio"}]]}}
```

---

code block

```
 def build_concept_with_paths(concept,parent_id=nil)
    concept['paths'] = []
    parent_id.nil? ? concept['paths'] << [concept['id']] : concept['paths'] << [{'id' => parent_id}, {'id' =>concept['id']}]
    concept
end

 def build_concept_data(concepts)
  concepts.keys.first(2).each_with_object({}) do |k,data|
      if k == 'children'
            concepts[k].each do |concept|
                child = build_concept_with_paths(concept,concepts['id'])
                data[child['id']] = child
                if concept['children']
                    build_concept_data(child)
                end
            end
            concept_id = concepts[k]
            concept = {'id' => concept_id,'paths' => [[{'id' => concept_id }]] }
            data[concepts[k]] = concept
      end
  end
end
```

My recursive call, doesn't seem to affect the final results, Im unable to return the results from the recursion. Any help would be great.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but if your graph is a tree you might want to consider the `rubytree` gem https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree.

Comment: Your initial hash has two keys, both `:id`. Hashes cannot have duplicate keys. Also, what you refer to as the "new hash" that you are building is not a hash (or any other Ruby object). You'll have to fix that before we can offer suggestions.

Comment: can you also please separate the big code block into different sections, because I don't understand, what the big data block in the beginning represents and which is the actual method for which you need help.